Is expired sushi rice still good
I found sushi rice from 2018, hermetically packed and it looks fine.
Is this still safe to eat and can I expect major structural or taste changes?

Hi, I'm afraid we don't answer "what can I use this for" questions, except in very limited circumstances. "Typical", "traditional" is not one of those - even if it seems to be a good, working restriction, it turns out not to be.

@rumtscho OK, fair enough, thanks for keeping the "allowed" part

By ‘sushi rice’, do you mean dry uncooked rice of a variety typically used for sushi, or pre-cooked rice used for sushi? The difference here is really important (as is whether or not it’s been seasoned if it’s pre-cooked).

@AustinHemmelgarn the former, yes. It is uncooked rice, vacuum sealed, labelled as "sushi rice". We do not have pre-cooked rice in France (at least in regular shops, but I've never seen any)

Some people believe that "aged rice" is best for Risotto, and Acquerello Carnaroli Rice is aged for seven years.

Dried foods, such as rice, which include "sushi rice", do not expire as other non-dried foods do.
Let's consider a practical real-life example from which we can infer from and have that inferred info applied directly to your case here: When you think about it, these dried foods are ideal for giving to food banks and charity drives because of their long shelf-life. They simply do not spoil in a short period of time as other non-dried foods may. That's why they're ideal for said purposes! Thus, if its good enough for that, it's probably good enough for us too.
Also, now, depending on your locale, sometimes, products are forced to have expiry dates or bb (best before) dates because of government regulation. Theories about why this exist may abound, but, the long-short of it is that you may not need to worry or fret about dried foods that are held past a best before date.
As a precaution, you may check for signs of spoilage via moisture, fungal growth, and infestation/vermin/rodent damage, as sometimes the storage method was poor or failed (say in the case of flooding) of one's storage area. But, generally speaking, if there is no foul smell, and everything is dry and clean, you should be perfect to make sushi.
Some foods tend to lose potency especially when they are high-flavor or herby or tend to spoil (or go rancid in the case of fats), over long periods of storage. But, rice should be fine, generally speaking.
I hope this helps.

Was that misspelling of ‘glutinous rice’ deliberate?  :-)

And not particularly glutenous.

Sushi rice is not sticky rice or glutinous rice - that is a misnomer.  Both sticky rice and glutinous rice are a different type of rice that has starch content - very low amylose content and high amounts of amylopectin (the glutinous textural component when cooked) that becomes translucent when cooked and is very 'sticky'. The short-grained Japanese  version is the type made into mochi and is also called sweet rice. Sushi rice is just short-grained 'normal' rice.  It could just be called short-grained or medium-grained rice.  Calrose is a variety of medium-grained rice developed in California.

Fowl = things like chickens; foul = yeuch.

To be fair @AndrewMorton if your dried rice smells like chicken you also should probably not be eating it.

Some of the nutritional value degrades over time. For beans, most of the vitamins will have degraded after 5 years, this isn't an issue with rice however as Rice has no vitamins/minerals.

@Questor Yup! :) Its just rice and its already dried or aged somewhat--especially for certain types like basmati.

LOL thank you everyone. Typical stack-exchange criticality but at least there's some light humor in the mix.

"Best by" dates are used for quality, not safety.  Cook it and give it a try.  The favor and/or texture may be impacted, but you will need to decide if that matters to you. As long as it is dry and bug free...this is not a safety issue.

Doesn't seem like there are high risks, besides it possibly not tasting the best (i.e. don't use it for your mom-in-law's dinner visit)
HealthLine Does Rice Go Bad?

Below are the shelf lives of each type of rice (1, 2):


White rice: up to 2 years
Brown rice: 3–6 months from the date of manufacture


Shelf-stable foods usually have an expiration date — often called best-by or use-by date. Still, they may be safely consumed after that date if there are no signs of deterioration on the product’s package (1).


Determining whether dry rice has gone bad is relatively easy.


Just check the package for spoilage signs, including holes, bugs, dampness, or water, which may lead to mold growth.


When it comes to brown rice specifically, you may also look for discolorations, a rancid or funny smell, or an oily texture.


The difference here is the Brown Rice still has the bran which is/part-of the "baby plant", and contains fats that decay.  White rice has the bran removed by being "polished".

I would be very wary.
I have been thinking, as the other answers here suggested, there is nothing in the rice that could go off, there are no fats - it is almost pure carbohydrate. However, I tried rice of similar age just this winter, and it was bad. Before cooking, it seemed more or less fine, maybe slight off-smell but that could be from outside or whatever, I thought. But the cooking emphasized it into smell similar to rancid oil (e.g., in old biscuits). Simply, it smelled terrible.
I would say for rice with best before date long gone, it must be 100 %  perfect or throw it out. And please, do have a backup if you are going to try it.
